# Making SQL/JPQL query to select all topics that matches both keywords

Tags: sql, jpql

**Challenge:**
I want to create a query that selects **Topics** that match both the **keyword** ID´s *"Java" and "sql"*, the **Topic** with *ID = 1* matches both **keywords** *"Java" and "Sql*.

I have implemented two simple **entities** *Topic and Keyword*. They have a bidirectional ManyToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Topic")
public class Topic implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "topicID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "topicTitle")
    private String title = "";
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Join_Topic_Keyword",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Topic_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Keyword_ID"))
    private Set<Keyword> keywords;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "Keyword")
public class Keyword implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "keywordID")
    private String id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "keywords")
    private Set<Topic> topics;
}
```

Here is the structure table.

[image]

And This is the result from `Join_Topic_Keyword`

[image]

Comment: Avoid give code use image

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please paste your table definitions and so forth directly into your question as using images makes it very difficult to follow. Sounds like a simple question and you will get a quick answer that way.

Comment: So you want the query to join `Topic` and `Keyword`?

Comment: Thx a lot for the editing. I think that a join is part of the query.

Comment: Of course join you are using are query, https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5736/query

Comment: I still have not found the answer